# How to store array of values in cookies using rails?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I want to save an array of values in cookie. I have a method called add_names. Whenever this method has been called i need to save the name in the cookie. I have tried the below code. But it's not working, it's keeping only the last value.

```
def add_names(name)
  cookies[:user_names] = name
end
```

Please suggest me a idea to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies store strings in it. Still if you need to store list of user names you can append names

```
cookies[:user_names] = '' if cookies[:user_names].nil?
cookies[:user_names] = cookies[:user_names] + "#{value} ,"
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do this:

```
cookies[:user_names] = @users.map { |user| user.name }
```

The problem is that in your `each` loop, you're redefining the value of the `:user_names` cookie to be a single user.

If you want to append a value to an existing array, then you can do this:

```
def add_names name
  # Initialize it to an empty array, if not set
  cookies[:user_names] ||= []
  # Then, append the user name
  cookies[:user_names] << name
end
```

Comment: I have just written a sample code. But my actual purpose is, whenever we are calling a method called "add" we should add the name content in the cookie